# MySQL: select value in table depending on which value is FIRST in another table

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

I have two tables. The first is called: Computers_F3. The second is a temporary table called "Advice".

I would like to select a value from the 'ProductImage' column of the Computers_F3 table. Which value I want to select, depends on which 'ProductID' is the **first** value in the 'Advice' table.

http://www.a-training.nl/test/illustratie.png

Is there a way to do this in one mysqli_query? The advice table is already sorted based on the score column. So I would just like to take the first value and use that to select a image from 'productimage'.

Hope you guys can help.

Comment: What determines the order of the Advice table? Is it the score?

Comment: It's indeed the score that determines the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ProductID,ProductImage
FROM Computers_F3 
WHERE ProductID=(SELECT ProductID
                 FROM Advice
                 ORDER BY Score DESC
                 LIMIT 1)
```

**OR** using `JOIN`:

```
SELECT T1.ProductID,T1.ProductImage
FROM Computers_F3 T1 JOIN
     Advice T2 ON T2.ProductID=T1.ProductID
ORDER BY T2.Score DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks mate! I used the first option. It works for the first value. However, when I want to choose the SECOND value by doing LIMIT 2, 2 it gives me an error. Is there another way to choose the second, third etc value?

Comment: @NvdB31: For the second value, you should use `LIMIT 2,1`.

Comment: You're absolutely awesome. Thanks a million. People here on Stack Overflow are really helping me learning web programming. You're one of them! thanks.